# How can i automatically update a field on a model in Django?

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am creating a chatting app, something like slack, I want to be able to update the participants' field on the Chat model for every new Contact on the website

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='friends', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Message(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(
        Contact, related_name='author_messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.contact.user.username


class Chat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Private Chat')
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, related_name='chats')
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(Message, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.pk)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to save the contact to a chat upon creation but it didn't work

Comment: ``` contact.chat_set.add```

Comment: Please post the full code of what you have tried and the result you got

Comment: `chat.participants.add(contact)`

Comment: This worked, Thank You